# Is it possible to connect a certain SKU purchase with a certain campaign?

Tags: google-analytics, transactions, analytics, campaign-monitor, attribution

We are able to track transactions on our e-commerce and also track people who landed on the website through a LinkedIn display campaign for instance. But not possible to know how to connect these 2 information. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up **User-ID** features: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en